# Word: Find and Replace/Format newlines using Wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I want to find all the paragraph marks in a document where there isn't any text before them (basically empty lines).

The reason I want to do this is because I have a very large file where newlines are not properly formatted but every time I tried with wildcard search and then tried to format the newlines, the text in the paragraph also got formatted which is not what I was looking for.

Nevertheless, I tried with some combinations but it also finds the paragraph marks that are preceded by any text or dot.

### Sample Text:

```
I don't want the paragraph mark at the end of this line.¶

 ¶

               ¶

       ¶

Don't want to select this line either¶

         ¶

 ¶

                   ¶

                            ¶
```

### Patterns that I've tried:

- `[!A-Za-z.]^13{3,}`
- `[!.]^13{3,}`
- `[!\.]^13{3,}`

---

*What should be done to achieve the solution to this problem? I'm waiting for any replies.*

Comment: What is selected/found when using this pattern `[!A-Za-z.]^13{3,}`?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio This pattern also selects the paragraph mark at the end of the line which is not empty, which isn't what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "^p" and substitute by nothing....